# Given an array of arrays, how can i find the total number of items in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array of orders, and in each order i have a list of images. I want to find the total number of images. I can easily do this iteratively, but I was wondering if there is a nice one liner way to do this in javascript.

EDIT - Orders is a list of order, and in each order there is a list of images.

Example:

```
orders = [{ orderId: "1", images: [{ imageId: 1}, { imageId: 2}]}]
```

My current approach:

```
let imageCounter = 0

orders.forEach((order) => {
    const images = get(order, 'images')
    images.forEach(() => {
        imageCounter++
    })
})
```

Anyone know of a nicer way to do what im trying to do here?

Comment: If you show your data people could give a better answer. A few ways to do it, but can not give an aswer without knowing what `orders` actually holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the `orders` array, and sum the length of the sub-arrays:

```js
const orders = [{ images: ["x","x","x"] },{ images: ["x","x","x"] },{ images:  ["x","x"] }];

const count = orders.reduce((s, a) => s + a.images.length, 0);

console.log(count);
```

If you're using lodash, you can use `_.sumBy()`:

```js
const orders = [{ images: ["x","x","x"] },{ images: ["x","x","x"] },{ images:  ["x","x"] }];

const count = _.sumBy(orders, 'images.length');

console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const orders = [{ orderId:"1", images: [ {imageId: 1}, {imageId: 2} ]},{ orderId:"2", images: [ {imageId: 3}, {imageId: 4}, {imageId: 5} ]}];
const result = orders.flatMap(o => o.images).length;
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate through the orders and sum the `length` of each `images` array:

```js
const orders = [
  { orderId:"1", images: [ {imageId: 1}, {imageId: 2} ]},
  { orderId:"2", images: [ {imageId: 3}, {imageId: 4}, {imageId: 5} ]}
];
const result = orders.reduce((sum,{images}) => sum+images.length, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner using `Array#reduce`.

```
const imageCount = orders.reduce((s, a) => s + get(order, 'images').length, 0);
```

Simplified test case:

```js
const orders = [[1, 2], [1,2], [2]];

const imageCount = orders.reduce((s, a) => s + a.length, 0);

console.log(imageCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing what your dataset actually is. Looks like an array of objects. Simple reduce can be used to count the number.

```js
const orders = [
  {images: [1,2,3]},
  {images: [4,5]},
  {images: [6]},
  {images: [7,8,9,10]}
]

const count = orders.reduce((c,{images}) => c + images.length, 0)

console.log(count)
```

without fat arrow

```js
const orders = [
  {images: [1,2,3]},
  {images: [4,5]},
  {images: [6]},
  {images: [7,8,9,10]}
]

const count = orders.reduce(function(c, obj) {
  return c + obj.images.length
}, 0)

console.log(count)
```